# Brother Label Printer SDK bPac 3.1 Failed to print

Tags: printing, sdk, brother-bpac

I've got the printer driver, P-touch Editor, b-PAC 3.1 and client tools, all 64-bit, downloaded from the Brother website and installed on my 64-bit Windows 7 laptop. The P-touch Editor works/prints fine.

However, b-PAC failed, and none of the samples worked.  I debugged the code:

```
bool b = doc.PrintOut(1, bpac.PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
```

where `b` is false.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I was hitting the same problem, everything appears to work right up to the point where I called "PrintOut", which fails with error 11, "The currently specified printer is not supported".

It turns out the problem I had was with the driver. I had installed the printer driver from the CDROM that came with the label printer. Windows 7 also comes with an "in-box" driver for the printer and in fact this is the one you should install (it's marked with an "LE" at the end).

To fix the problem, all you need to do is go to the "Devices and Printers" dialog, select the printer, right click on it and select "Printer properties", select the "Advanced" tab and click "New Driver". Find the printer in the list that matches yours but with an "LE" at the end and click OK.

Printing is possible with either of the drivers using the P-Touch editor. Odd thing is, "LE" appears to stand for "Light Edition", but the "Heavy" version doesn't work!... strange.

Comment: This answer is extremly helpful. I think it should definetly work with both, especially because P-Touch Editor actually complains, when you do not have the "Heavy" version installed.

Answer (score 3):

On my Windows 10 x64 machine, I've had a similar issue using Ruby to print through the bPAC SDK (using win32ole). My code worked on another machine, but not mine.

After fighting with this for a long time, I figured out that all was fine and dandy when using the **32 bit** version of the bPAC SDK (and Ruby). Don't know exactly what went wrong here, but it might be that the 64bit SDK is just broken.

Comment: But did you install the 64bit or 32bit drivers?

Comment: After spending 3 days on my .netcore project I can 100% confirm the there has to be a bug with 64bit I have raised a helpdesk ticket with brother dev team the printer I am running is QL-700. by changing CPU from 64bit to 32bit it definitely worked for me. also doc.ErrorCode is helpful in debugging the issue.

Comment: @Wazzie did you ever hear back from them?

Comment: @frankenapps No mate I did not hear from them the work is to work with 32bit for now :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so I added this after the `printOut` to see which code I was getting.

```
string sError = doc.ErrorCode
```

It returned `Error 11`, which corresponds to "Device is not supported", but the device was a QL-570 which IS supported.

To get it working, I used the following steps:

1. Side-install the 32bits sdk.
2. Open your 64bit sample.
3. Change target configuration platform from "any cpu" to "x86"
4. Compile

**See also:** [Label printing development using b-pac SDK in a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11166063/4639281)

Answer (score 1):

Some printers only support 32-bit b-PAC SDK ver.
(even if you use windows 10 64-bit with Excel 64-bit)
please check:
https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/dev/en/bpac/environment/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is the application that you uses.

If your app is a 32bitapp (inclusive excel) you need the bPAC SDK for 32bit even when they are running on 64-bit Windows OS.

Comment: If I use a 64 bit app (i.e. my Ruby app) and the 64bit SDK things stop working, only when having both on 32bits seems to work.
What do you mean with 'inclusive Excel', is this relying on the installed Ms Office version somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (printOut gave me the error code 11).
The error appeared after switching from the printer PT-9800 to PT-P950.
Trying 32 and 64bit did not work for me.

What fixed it was uninstalling the driver of the PT-9800. I found a hint in the b-PAC 3.4 SDK Help in the section Troubleshooting: "if the old label printer will no longer be used, we recommend deleting the printer driver."